# I am not able to sign in google play services. I am getting this exception "com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 4: 4:"

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-play-services, google-play-console

I am trying to add google play services in my android game. I have followed all the steps shown in https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling this link.
I have added the app id in AndroidManifest.xml file.
Then, I followed the steps shown in this https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/signin link.
I am still getting this exception "com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 4: 4:" everytime. I guess the status code I am getting as a result is SIGN_IN_REQUIRED.
Do I have to release it for testing on the google play console. Can not I just test it by running on a physical device by using android studio?

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    var googleLogInResult =
        registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->

            if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                // There are no request codes
                val result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(result.data)
                if (result.isSuccess) {
                    // The signed in account is stored in the result.
                    val signedInAccount = result.signInAccount
                } else {
                    var message = result.status.statusMessage
                    if (message == null || message.isEmpty()) {
                        message = "signin_other_error"
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        window.setFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
        )
    }

    private fun signInSilently() {
        val signInOptions = GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN
        val account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this)
        if (GoogleSignIn.hasPermissions(account, *signInOptions.scopeArray)) {
            // Already signed in.
            // The signed in account is stored in the 'account' variable.
            val signedInAccount = account
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Account is already signed in")
        } else {
            // Haven't been signed-in before. Try the silent sign-in first.
            val signInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, signInOptions)
            signInClient
                .silentSignIn()
                .addOnCompleteListener(
                    this
                ) { task ->
                    if (task.isSuccessful) {
                        // The signed in account is stored in the task's result.
                        val signedInAccount = task.result
                        Log.d("MainActivity", "sign in successful")
                    } else {
                        // Player will need to sign-in explicitly using via UI.
                        // See [sign-in best practices](http://developers.google.com/games/services/checklist) for guidance on how and when to implement Interactive Sign-in,
                        // and [Performing Interactive Sign-in](http://developers.google.com/games/services/android/signin#performing_interactive_sign-in) for details on how to implement
                        // Interactive Sign-in.
                        startSignInIntent()
                        /*Log.d("dsds", "sign in failed: " + (task.exception as ApiException).statusCode)*/
                        Log.d("MainActivity", "sign in failed: " + task.exception)
                    }
                }
        }
    }

    private fun startSignInIntent() {
        val signInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(
            this,
            GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN
        )
        val intent = signInClient.signInIntent
        googleLogInResult.launch(intent)
    }


    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        signInSilently()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I found my problem. I was logged in from different google account and it was not my tester account.